# Angular 1.4.x numeric field with gettersetter not working for decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, numeric, getter-setter

I have a problem in chrome(47) where when using an input of type number in combination with ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" does not allow you to enter decimal numbers in the field.

With getterSetter: (not working)

```
<input ng-model="amount" ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" step="0.01" type="number" >
```

Without getterSetter: (works)

```
<input ng-model="_amount" step="0.01" type="number">
```

see plunker for a demo
http://plnkr.co/edit/qu8UXCUtkJaFwjgGE1NX?p=preview

Comment: works for me. (Chrome 46)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening there is that when you declare a `getterSetter` function, this function is being called everytime you modify the input's value.

So when you write "12." the function is being called, but that is not a valid number, so it takes out the "." for providing a valid value.

Try typing "123" and then adding a "." between numbers such as "12.3" that works!

**Edit**

I have fixed your code, now it works.

Try this:

```
 $scope.amount = function(newValue) {
  return arguments.length ? ($scope._amount = newValue) : $scope._amount;
};
```

Here is a forked plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/xZtZLH5He4ZnjkqhFApY?p=preview

Comment: As you can see in the console this is not happening. when you press . the getter is fired but it never fires the setter. also the provided answer is not a valid workaround.

Comment: I was not providing a workaround with that, I was just showing you how it worked, just an example for you to understand why was that happening.

And as I have already told you, undefined is being logged in the console because "12." means nothing